# Postgres Bulk Data Import and Populate Associated Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a Postgres database that gets updated from various external sources several times a day, and each record has fields like company_id and user_id that need to get looked up from an existing table and saved with the record. Currently, I'm using Ruby to loop through the new records and get the company and user IDs with an ActiveRecord query. This is terribly inefficient, though.

What's an efficient method to do this? Can it be done with a `JOIN` query on update?

Comment: Please show the table definitions and queries. Otherwise there's too much guesswork. you should also always mention your versions (PostgreSQL, Ruby, etc) in questions. Show what you're already doing too. (Reply here once you edit and I'll take a look).

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how you load the data, if you load it with "copy" than you cant look it up during import process. I have the same situation here, this is how i do it:

1) import data into a IMPORT table

```
\copy importtable (companyname, what, ever, i , need) from 'FILE' WITH DELIMITER AS ';' CSV HEADER;
```

2) this step is necessary if you import new companies/users who do not have an existing ID already. it queries the companies without ID and creates new IDs

```
INSERT INTO company (companyid,companyname)
SELECT  companyname
FROM importtable
        LEFT OUTER JOIN company ON (importtable.companyname=company.companyname)
WHERE company.companyid is NULL
GROUP BY companyname;
```

3) insert the whole import table into the consolidation table

```
INSERT INTO consolidationable(companyid, what,ever,you,need )
SELECT companyid, what,ever,you,need
  FROM importtable
        INNER JOIN company ON (importtable.companyname=company.companyname);
```

nice thing is, it uses COPY so the import itself is fast, and then it uses all buffers because postgreSQL can query all company IDs at once. it is can run highly parallel when you create several import tables.